# Can't scroll Y on a position fixed element

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I have developed a VueJS component which allow an Y scroll. I have 2 elements which have 100vh height each. On the bottom of this component, I have a div on a fixed position. If I scroll down with my mouse or my finger on mobile on this fixed element, the container won't allow me to scroll down.

My component code just below:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <div id="weatherIcon" class="flex justify-end relative overflow-hidden h-1/3">
      <img class="absolute cover-enter-active max-h-full" :src="props.weather.cover" alt="Weather cover" />
    </div>
    <div id="texts" class="flex-col flex texts-enter-active pl-5">
      <div id="temperature">
        <p class="font-bold">{{ Math.round(props.temperature) }}°</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex items-center" id="weatherDescription">
        <img :src="props.weather.icon" alt="Rain" />
        <p class="ml-1 font-light text-base">{{ props.weather.credo }}</p>
      </div>
      <div id="city">
        <p class="font-bold">{{ props.city }}</p>
      </div>
      <div id="cityDescription" class="py-5">
        <p class="font-light pr-5">{{ props.description.length > 150 ? props.description.slice(0, 150) : props.description }}... <a v-if="props.wikiLink" :href="props.wikiLink" class="font-bold" :style="{ color: weather.moreFont }">en savoir plus</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ref="swipeElement" id="swipe" class="mt-auto mb-6 fixed bottom-0 w-full">
      <div id="baseSwap" class="flex flex-col font-bold items-center swipe-enter-active w-full">
        <p>Glisser pour voyager</p>
        <img :src="swipe"  alt="Swipe icon" class="swipe opacity-80"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I have partially solved the problem by reducing the container width to it's own size and not full screen size. But still have the problem if I want to swipe from the fixed text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try disabling pointer events on the fixed position element, which will allow scroll events to propagate to its parent container. Add the following CSS to your fixed position element:

```
#swipe{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I have tried it in your website using Chrome developer tools it worked
[image]